# Cannot resolve column 'account_id'

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

Like pictures, I can't set name for column
I use Hibernate 6.4.4

I'm trying to create a relationship between Account and Person but I get the error "Cannot resolve column 'accound_id' ", I've done the mapping but still get the above error.

```
<mapping class="com.bravos2k5.models.Account"/>
<mapping class="com.bravos2k5.models.Person"/>
```

Account class:
@Entity
public class Account {

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Getter
@Setter
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
private String username;

@Getter
@Setter
@Column(nullable = false)
private String password;

@Getter
@Setter
@Column(unique = true)
private String email;

@Getter
@Setter
@Column(unique = true)
private String phone;

@Getter
@Setter
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();

private Boolean isBan;

public void setBan(Boolean isBan) {
    this.isBan = isBan;
}

public Boolean isBan() {
    return isBan;
}

public Account() {}

public Account(String username, String password, String email, String phone, Boolean isBan) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.isBan = isBan;
}

public Account(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

}
```

Person class:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person {
    public static boolean FEMALE = false;
    public static boolean MALE = true;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private Boolean gender;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id") // Problem here
    private Account account;
    
    public Person() {
    
    }
}
```

Pls help me resolve this problem

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as [properly formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Is there an account_id column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code in **Person** class.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Account account;
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in your question:

In your database, you have one table for your `Person` instances. Each one of those is associated to up to one `Account` instance, via the column `account_id` in the person table. This column does not exist.

What you can do is:

- create the column manually
- add a migration to a potential database migration tool like Flyway
- use hibernates ddl-auto function to automatically create that column for you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
```

which maps to a non existing column use

```
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
```

which exists based on your code